# Version Control for Visual Studio projects and MS Dynamics CRM (javascript)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm looking for Version Control that warns a use when opening a file if that file is being modified by another user. Is this possible?

We also use Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and are looking to use some kind of version control for the javascript files. Does someone has experience with using Dynamics CRM and version control?

Thank you for any information!

Answer (score 4):

You could implement this in Team Foundation Server (TFS) or other version control applications that support single checkout.  You will need to either manually deploy the JScript or create an auto deployment process through the SDK.  TFS will need to be setup for single checkout which will only allow a single user to checkout the files at a given time.  This should disallow multiple people from making edits at once.  It is a good idea to appoint a single person as the build master who will be in charge of merging changes into CRM.

EDIT: JScript is syntactically very close to JavaScript.  Microsoft CRM uses and has always used JScript for its form scripting.  JScript is basically Microsofts version of JavaScript.  Differences are discussed @ [What's the difference between JavaScript and JScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135203/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jscript) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript

Excerpt from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK:

> Microsoft JScript libraries are Script (JScript) Web Resources that contain functions you can use to:
>
> > Handle form and field events.
> >
> > Perform actions for controls configured in the Ribbon.
> >
> > Support other functions.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint. I'll look for some more information on this. There is one thing i don't get in your answer. Why do i need to create a JScript?