# User-friendly tool for editing MS CRM customization xml

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to make a lot of modifications in MS CRM customization. Some of these customizations could be made in web-interface, dome of them need to be hacked in plain customization XML file.

Even more, I'm not the one who is making changes: so I will be required to merge these changes done by one person in web-interface and by another one in plane XML. But MS CRM automatically produces quite big and fairly readable customization file where it's impossible to understand which changes belongs to what.

Is there any tool to make this editing a bit easier? Maybe someone faced with such an issue already and have their own solution for that? Maybe converting to YAML or JSON, editing and then converting back?

Any best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is an answer. Right from Microsoft itself:

[Use the SolutionPackager Tool to Compress and Extract a Solution File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602987.aspx)

This tool provided as part of standard [MS Dynamics CRM SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004) and enables developer to split customization files on pieces and then combine it back again.

But, frankly speaking, on MS Dynamics CRM 2011 Rollup 10 SDK it's broken: in some cases it is unable to split solutions and is **unable to combine them back in all cases**.

Answer (score 0):

Well wont everyone be loading their customisations into CRM to test them? In that case you can let CRM merge the changes and you can just take an export.

If they are working in separate environments then use CRM solutions to import the customisations into a single environment.