# What programming languages do TestComplete support?

Tags: programming-languages, automated-tests, testcomplete

I have started learning of "Test Complete" an automated testing tool. I have downloaded and installed it on Windows 7. Now I want to write Test script. But unfortunately I am novice and I don't know what programming language does it support.

BTW, I'm familiar with Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestComplete supports [5 scripting languages](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/31935/) for creating tests: VBScript, JScript, DelphiScript, C++Script and C#Script. **VBScript** and **JScript** are standard Microsoft scripting languages that are used on web pages and for running Windows Script Host scripts. **DelphiScript** is a similar language provided by SmartBear that has the Delphi/Pascal syntax. As for **C++Script** and **C#Script** languages, they are just modifications of the JScript language and are needed only if you are working with C++ or C# Connected Applications.

So, if you are familiar with Java, the best choice is **JScript**. You can find the language reference in the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98.aspx).

Comment: What is JScript? Is it JavaScript? or different from JS?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim: Both JavaScript and JScript are ECMAScript implementations. The difference is that JavaScript is used for browser scripting, whereas Microsoft JScript is used for Windows shell scripting (similar to VBScript, batch files, PowerShell etc.) See also see [What's the difference between JavaScript and JScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/135203/113116)

Comment: Thanks Helen. Let me visit the site.

Comment: 1.Info about scripting online; http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/58094/   ; 2.MS jscript aka ecmascript aka js docs Scripting ; ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950396.aspx